# Can I use maven archetype if that archetype is in Maven repo but not listed in interactive mode

Tags: maven

I have a working archetype for some open source project, I can install it and then use when mvn archetype:generate using local catalog. I would like to share it so anybody can use it in his/her project. Project is already on Maven public repository using OSS Sonatype. Sonatype packages archetype in jar file and says that its normal dependency, so here is my question: Is it possible for user to use my archetype when I use traditional releasing process in OSS Sonatype in this way:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=pl.bristleback -DarchetypeArtifactId=webapp-archetype
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Generate project using an alternative catalog](http://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/examples/generate-alternative-catalog.html) told us as

> It is possible to use an alternative catalog as the internal one by defining the archetypeCatalog property to a specific value which can be one of:
>
> 1. **`internal`** to use the internal catalog only.
> 2. **`local`** to use the local catalog only.
> 3. **`remote`** to use the maven's remote catalog. No catalog is currently provided.
> 4. **`file://path/to/archetype-catalog.xml`** to use a specific local catalog. When the catalog file is named `archetype-catalog.xml`, it can be omitted.
> 5. **`http://url/to/archetype-catalog.xml`** to use a specific remote catalog. When the catalog file is named `archetype-catalog.xml`, it can be omitted.

The you may try to create by using the following command: -

```
mvn archetype:generate 
    -DarchetypeCatalog=http://path/to/your/sonartype 
    -DarchetypeGroupId=pl.bristleback 
    -DarchetypeArtifactId=webapp-archetype
```

I hope this may help.